# Java Regular Expression ReplaceAll with Regex Result to Trim Whitespace Before and After delimiters

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter, replaceall

I gave it my best shot and this is what I have so far.

```
String input = "hey,what up man:1033:yes,okay that makes sense     ,not:       okay:1111,     aaaaa,bbbbb";
String input2 = input.replaceAll("(.*)\\s([^:,])+\\s(.*)", "\1\2\3");
String arguments[] = input2.split("[:,]");
```

> Expected output:
>   arguments[0] ="hey";
>   arguments[1]="what up
>   man";
>   arguments[2]="1033";
>   arguments[3]="yes";
>  
>   arguments[4]="okay that makes sense";
>   arguments[5]="not";
>   arguments[6]="okay";
>   arguments[7]="1111";
>  
>   arguments[8]="aaaaa";
>   arguments[9]="bbbbb";

Pretty much I need to be able to get all 10 arguments and strip the Whitespace right before each of the delimiters `;` and `,` and all the Whitespace right after each of the delimiters.

Would be cool if it's possible to do this with just split alone without replaceAll, I assume with some very expert regex skills anything is possible in a one liner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include whitespaces surrounding your delimiters by adding `\\s*`. Try this way

```
String arguments[] = input.split("\\s*[:,]\\s*");
```

DEMO:

```
String input = "hey,what up man:1033:yes,okay that makes sense     ,not:       okay:1111,     aaaaa,bbbbb";
String arguments[] = input.split("\\s*[:,]\\s*");
for (int i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
    System.out.println(i+")"+arguments[i]);
}
```

output:

```
0)hey
1)what up man
2)1033
3)yes
4)okay that makes sense
5)not
6)okay
7)1111
8)aaaaa
9)bbbbb
```

Comment: @SSpoke Glad you like it :)

Comment: These regex wizards can do the impossible, and it looks so simple haha